# SMTP PHP Mail Error

Tags: php, email, variables, smtp, syntax-error

I am including PHP variables in my smtp google mail. However, everytime it causes an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_string in line ___
```

For example, say the PHP variables are received via HTTP POST

This is the section of the mail's code where the T_string, syntax error is coming:

```
<td class='w580' width='580'>
<p align='center' class='article-title' style='color: #de0303;'><singleline label='Title'>New Event For $clubName</singleline></p>
<div align='justify' class='article-content'>
<multiline label='Description'>
<p align="left">

    Club: $clubName <br>
    Event Name: $eventName <br>
            Description: $description <br>
        Location: $venue <br>
</multiline>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the surrounding code it's impossible to say why the syntax error is occurring. What you've posted is pure HTML (albeit with PHP-style variable names embedded). My guess is that the double quotes are causing the problem - change them to single quotes.

Comment: how stupid of me, yes, that was it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Mike W, the solution is to change the double quotes in the

tag back to single quotes.